# How to prevent back slide in ios react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

after user login and taking to home screen if user slide from left side it will take him back to login screen, how do i prevent that ?

i tried a lot of solutions say's `navigationOptions: {gesturesEnabled: false, },`

AppNavigation.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Animated, Easing, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  DrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import {
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
  reduxifyNavigator
} from "react-navigation-redux-helpers";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import CategoryScreen from "../screens/CategoryScreen";
import DetailScreen from "../screens/DetailScreen";
import ListingScreen from "../screens/ListingScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import MapScreen from "../screens/MapScreen";
import SavedListingScreen from "../screens/SavedListingScreen";
import SearchScreen from "../screens/SearchScreen";
import SignupScreen from "../screens/SignupScreen";
import WelcomeScreen from "../screens/WelcomeScreen";
import { AppIconDark, AppStyles, AppStylesDark, } from "../AppStyles";
import { Configuration } from "../Configuration";
import DrawerContainer from "../components/DrawerContainer";

const noTransitionConfig = () => ({
  transitionSpec: {
    duration: 0,
    timing: Animated.timing,
    easing: Easing.step0
  }
});

const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  "root",
  state => state.nav
);

// login stack
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Signup: { screen: SignupScreen },
    Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Welcome",
    headerMode: "float",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.main,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle, headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
    }),
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background }
  }
);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen,  },
    Listing: { screen: ListingScreen },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen },
    Map: { screen: MapScreen }
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    headerMode: "float",

    headerLayoutPreset: "center",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      //Back Button
      headerTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.main,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle, headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
    }),
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }
  }
);

const CollectionStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Category: { screen: CategoryScreen },
    Listing: { screen: ListingScreen },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen },
    Map: { screen: MapScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Category",
    headerMode: "float",
    headerLayoutPreset: "center",
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      //Back in Collection "ALl Others" Page
      headerTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.main,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle, 
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
    })
  }
);

const SavedListingStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SavedListing: { screen: SavedListingScreen },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen },
    Map: { screen: MapScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "SavedListing",
    headerMode: "float",
    headerLayoutPreset: "center",
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      //Back in Save
      headerTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.main,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle, headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
    })
  }
);

const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: { screen: SearchScreen },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen },
    Map: { screen: MapScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Search",
    headerMode: "float",
    headerLayoutPreset: "center",
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      //Back in Search
      headerTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.main,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle, headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
    })
  }
);

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Categories: { screen: CollectionStack },
    Saved: { screen: SavedListingStack },
    Search: { screen: SearchStack }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "Home") {
          iconName = AppIconDark.images.home;
        } else if (routeName === "Categories") {
          iconName = AppIconDark.images.collections;
        } else if (routeName === "Saved") {
          iconName = AppIconDark.images.heart;
        } else if (routeName === "Search") {
          iconName = AppIconDark.images.search;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        return (
          <Image
            style={{
              tintColor: focused ? AppStylesDark.color.main : AppStylesDark.color.grey
            }}
            source={iconName}
          />
        );
      }
    }),
    initialLayout: {
      height: 300
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      //Active " selected Tab "
      activeTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.main,
      inactiveTintColor: AppStylesDark.color.grey,
      style: {
        height: Configuration.home.tab_bar_height,
        backgroundColor: AppStylesDark.color.background
      }
    }
  }
);

// drawer stack
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Tab: TabNavigator
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tab",
    drawerWidth: 200,
    drawerPosition: "right",
    contentComponent: DrawerContainer,
    drawerType: "slide",
  }
);

// Manifest of possible screens
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginStack: { screen: LoginStack },
    DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
  },
  {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "DrawerStack",
    transitionConfig: noTransitionConfig,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      color: "black"
    })
  }
);

const AppWithNavigationState = reduxifyNavigator(RootNavigator, "root");

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state: state.nav
});

const AppNavigator = connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: "normal",
    textAlign: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    //Title
    color: AppStylesDark.color.main,
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.main
  }
});

export { RootNavigator, AppNavigator, middleware };
```

i expect the user when slide from left to right, not to take him back to login screen again

the image below show's how user slide from left to right and it tock back to loading which is the previous screen before the home screen show up.

[image: Image shows how user slide from left to the right]

Comment: don't you just wanna reset your navstack upon login? try looking into `navigation.reset` instead of `navigation.navigate`

Answer (score 3):

Example: {
    name: 'Example Screen',
    screen: ExampleView
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
},